# Unicorn CPU usage spiking during load tests, ways to optimize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, optimization, load, unicorn

I am interested in ways to optimize my Unicorn setup for my Ruby on Rails 3.1.3 app. I'm currently spawning 14 worker processes on High-CPU Extra Large Instance since my application appears to be CPU bound during load tests. At about 20 requests per second replaying requests on a simulation load tests, all 8 cores on my instance get peaked out, and the box load spikes up to 7-8. Each unicorn instance is utilizing about 56-60% CPU.

I'm curious what are ways that I can optimize this? I'd like to be able to funnel more requests per second onto an instance of this size. Memory is completely fine as is all other I/O. CPU is getting tanked during my tests.

Comment: Do you use ruby 1.9? If not, that might help.

Comment: Profile your code (ruby-prof) find out why it's slow, try to rewrite the bottleneck. Repeat until fast enough. With 0 information we can't guess why your code isn't faster

Comment: @randombits, if each CPU core can only process ~2 requests per second, something inside your app is *seriously* slow. You don't need to optimize your Unicorn setup. You need to optimize your application code. You haven't posted any profiling data -- is that because setting up and running the profiler seems troublesome? Or maybe you are still hoping the problem can be solved by tweaking your Unicorn config? (It can't.) For starters, look at your Rails log, identify the slow requests, and tell us what it reports for "DB", "View", and overall time.

Answer (score 6):

If you are CPU bound you want to use no more unicorn processes than you have cores, otherwise you overload the system and slow down the scheduler.  You can test this on a dev box using ab.  You will notice that 2 unicorns will outperform 20 (number depends on cores, but the concept will hold true).

The exception to this rule is if your IO bound.  In which case add as many unicorns as memory can hold.

A good performance trick is to route IO bound requests to a different app server hosting many unicorns.  For example, if you have a request that uses a slow sql query, or your waiting on an external request, such as a credit card transaction.  If using nginx, define an upstream server for the IO bound requests, forward those urls to a box with 40 unicorns.  CPU bound or really fast requests, forward to a box with 8 unicorns (you stated you have 8 cores, but on aws you might want to try 4-6 as their schedulers are hypervised and already very busy).

Also, I'm not sure you can count on aws giving you reliable CPU usage, as your getting a percentage of an obscure percentage.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you probably don't want instances at 45-60% cpu. In that case, if you get a traffic spike, all of your instances will choke.

Next, 14 Unicorn instances seems large. Unicorn does not use threading. Rather, each process runs with a single thread. Unicorn's master process will only `select` a thread if it is able to handle it. Because of this, the number of cores isn't a metric you should use to measure performance with Unicorn.

A more conservative setup may use 4 or so Unicorn processes per instance, responding to maybe 5-8 requests per second. Then, adjust the number of instances until your CPU use is around 35%. This will ensure stability under the stressful '20 requests per second scenario.'

Lastly, you can get more gritty stats and details by using [`God`](http://godrb.com/).

Comment: 1) The OP said this is during load testing, so this *is* a traffic spike. 2) What does not having threaded processes have to do with the number of cores?

Answer (score 1):

For a high CPU extra large instance, 20 requests per second is *very* low. It is likely there is an issue with the code.  A unicorn-specific problem seems less likely. If you are in doubt, you could try a different app server and confirm it still happens.

In this scenario, questions I'd be thinking about...

1 - Are you doing something CPU intensive in code--maybe something that should really be in the database.  For example, if you are bringing back a large recordset and looping through it in ruby/rails to sort it or do some other operation, that would explain a CPU bottleneck at this level as opposed to within the database.  The recommendation in this case is to revamp the query to do more and take the burden off of rails.  For example, if you are sorting the result set in your controller, rather than through sql, that would cause an issue like this.

2 - Are you doing anything unusual compared to a vanilla crud app, like accessing a shared resource, or anything where contention could be an issue?

3 - Do you have any loops that might burn CPU, especially if there was contention for a resource?

4 - Try unhooking various parts of the controller logic in question. For example, how well does it scale if you hack your code to just return a static hello world response instead? I bet suddenly unicorn will be blazlingly fast. Then try adding back in parts of your code until you discover the source of the slowness.